# How to change database server for sharepoint farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database

I have a SharePoint farm with multiple content DBS, but I will shutdown database server because we need to use a different one.

I realized the people who installed this didn't use SQL alias.

I know how to make the backup and restore in SQL, and I know how to identify all SharePoint databases.

But how can I tell SharePoint (I guess with PowerShell), to change the database server name for ALL databases including Farm Config, central admin DB, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the SQL server name used by SharePoint for the Configuration database (and probably it's not that easy for all other DB).
So, the simplest solution is to create an alias now for the old server name!
I mean:
Let's say your old SQL is 'A' and you want to move all DBs to 'B': after restoring all DBs on B, create an alias on all SharePoint servers (with tool "cliconfg.exe") to make name 'A' point to 'B'.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method to move the database to new SQL Server and update SharePoint with new SQL server.

- Stop all SharePoint related service, So that no connection makes to SQL server during the migration.
- Stop IIS
- Backup the SQL Server
- Restored it to New Server
- Make Sure Permission sets properly.
- Now create SQL Alias on All SharePoint server so that it connect to new SQL Server. to Create SQL Alias Follow this

  - in the command prompt run **CLICONFG** and enter the Data like this.[image]
- Start all SharePoint Service
- Start IIS
- Test now.
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664029/Migrate-SharePoint-s-SQL-Server-to-another-SQL-Ser